# How to use str.replace with function transfer

Tags: php, jquery, forms

Good day.
I use this code to duplicate value from one input to other:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function transfer(which) {
document.getElementById("temp_name").value = which;
}
</script>
<form action="register.php" method="post" name="register">
<input type="text" name="username" id = "username" onkeyup = "transfer(this.value)"><br>
<input type="text" name="temp_name" id = "temp_name">
</form>
```

This duplicate #username to #temp_name
But I need that added text #temp_name without extra hypens and lowercase.
So I need somehow add this code  to upper code:

```
.replace(/\s/g,'-'); // to replace spaces with hypens
tmp_str = tmp_str.replace(/[\-]+/g,'-');    // to remove extra hypens
tmp_str = tmp_str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase(); // to convert to lower case and only allow alpabets and number and hypehn
tmp_str = alltrimhyphen(tmp_str);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution, just replace `tmp_str` by `which` like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function transfer(which) {
        which = which.replace(/\s/g,'-'); // to replace spaces with hypens
        which = which.replace(/[\-]+/g,'-');    // to remove extra hypens
        which = which.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]/g,'').toLowerCase(); // to convert to lower case 
        document.getElementById("temp_name").value = which;
   }
</script>

<form action="register.php" method="post" name="register">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" onkeyup="javascript:transfer(this.value);">
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="temp_name" id="temp_name">
</form>
```